# no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector for utilization of mclust

Tags: r, bioconductor, coercion

I'm trying to use the **mclust** method on an **.FCS** format file (which is a flow cytometry format file) and I read this file into R as flowFrame object.

```
install.packages("openCyto") # since the old version sefaulted my R session
library( openCyto )
library(  flowCore)
library(  mclust)

 trial1=read.FCS("export_Alcina TregMAIT_AV 10-1974 P1_CD4.fcs") 
 a=as.matrix(trial1)
```

Editors note: some of these are Bioconductor packages and you should install according to the help pages for that environment.

However, `mclust` does not accept the .fcs file as a matrix & I tried to convert it to a matrix with the function **as.matrix**, and I get this error:

```
Error in as.vector(data) :
  no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
```

I've found similar questions where they explain you have to add `importMethodsFrom(S4Vectors,as.matrix)` into the NAMESPACE of `mclust`, which I did. I also did `importMethodsFrom(BiocGenerics,as.vector)` in the NAMESPACE of mclust. However, I'm still not able to use `mclust`.

P.S. any advice or reading would be appreciated!

If, anyone knows other clustering methods that use GMM model that could accept .FCS format without converting, I'd be very happy.

Comment: You need to provide a pointer to a location for an example of an .FCS file and show what methods have been used to bring it into the R workspace. Presumably you have loaded a library or libraries and run some code but have not yet included those. Edit your question to include it.

Comment: Hi, I've used read.FCS funtion of flowCore package to open bring it into R. The .fcs file was already in the working directory, do simply:trial1=read.FCS("export_Alcina TregMAIT_AV 10-1974 P1_CD4.fcs"). trial1=read.FCS("export_Alcina TregMAIT_AV 10-1974 P1_CD4.fcs")
a=as.matrix(trial1)

I've run libraries openCyto, flowCore, mclust.

Answer (score 0):

I've edited your question to show what you should have done originally and also didn't do later (instead of including code in a comment you should have responded by then editing the question as was specifically suggested.) My response is based on the first example in `flowCore::read.FCS` (since you also did not include a pointer to the dataset you were loading from disk) so rather than "trial1" I will be referring to the "samp" object I get running that code.

The "samp" object is now returns this from `class` and `str`:

```
> class(samp)
[1] "flowFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "flowCore"
str(samp)
Formal class 'flowFrame' [package "flowCore"] with 3 slots
  ..@ exprs      : num [1:10000, 1:8] 382 628 1023 373 1023 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..$ : Named chr [1:8] "FSC-H" "SSC-H" "FL1-H" "FL2-H" ...
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:8] "$P1N" "$P2N" "$P3N" "$P4N" ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "ranges")= num [1:8] 1023 1023 10000 10000 10000 ...
  ..@ parameters :Formal class 'AnnotatedDataFrame' [package "Biobase"] with 4 slots
  .. .. ..@ varMetadata      :'data.frame': 5 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. .. .. ..$ labelDescription: chr [1:5] "Name of Parameter" "Description of Parameter" "Range of Parameter" "Minimum Parameter Value after Transforamtion" ...
  .. .. ..@ data             :'data.frame': 8 obs. of  5 variables:
  .. .. .. ..$ name    :Class 'AsIs'  Named chr [1:8] "FSC-H" "SSC-H" "FL1-H" "FL2-H" ...
  .. .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:8] "$P1N" "$P2N" "$P3N" "$P4N" ...
  .. .. .. ..$ desc    :Class 'AsIs'  Named chr [1:8] "FSC-H" "SSC-H" NA NA ...
  .. .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:8] "$P1S" "$P2S" "$P3S" "$P4S" ...
  .. .. .. ..$ range   : num [1:8] 1024 1024 1024 1024 1024 ...
  .. .. .. ..$ minRange: num [1:8] 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0
  .. .. .. ..$ maxRange: num [1:8] 1023 1023 10000 10000 10000 ...
  .. .. ..@ dimLabels        : chr [1:2] "rowNames" "columnNames"
  .. .. ..@ .__classVersion__:Formal class 'Versions' [package "Biobase"] with 1 slot
  .. .. .. .. ..@ .Data:List of 1
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1:3] 1 1 0
  ..@ description:List of 164
  .. ..$ FCSversion                : chr "2"
  .. ..$ $BYTEORD                  : chr "4,3,2,1"
  .. ..$ $DATATYPE                 : chr "F"
  #----- output truncated -----------
```

So "samp" is not a rectangular objects in any sense but rather a complex list with lots of the associated information in attributes. My guess is that you want the information in the `@ exprs` node which *is* a matrix.

A further difficulty is that there is no function mamed `mclust` in the mclust package, although looking at `?mclust` we do see an example demonstrating the use of an `Mclust` function. R is unforgiving in its insistence on correct capitalization of function names.

```
Mclust(exprs(samp)[1:100,])
#-----------
'Mclust' model object:
 best model: ellipsoidal, equal orientation (VVE) with 4 components
```